# android- can't remove item from database onLongItemClickListener listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite

I've a cursor adapter that fills  the listview , it works fine .
I want to remove an item with `onLongItemClickListener`.
I wrote this code but I know it's wrong because I don't know what is the databse row id .

```
        lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,final int position, long id) {

            builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setMessage(R.string.deleteit)
                   .setCancelable(true)
                   .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                           // myDb.deleteRow(position);
                       }
                   });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
            return false;
        }

    });
```

I logged third item from `onItemLongClick (id)` , for each  row it **returns -1** .

this is how I fill my listView

```
cursor = myDb.getAllRows();
adapter_comments = new TimeListAdapter(MainActivity.this, cursor);
lv.setAdapter(adapter_comments);
```

this is my cursorAdapter

```
public class TimeListAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    public TimeListAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvTitle;
        TextView tvt9;

        public ViewHolder(View row) {
            tvTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.title);
            tvt9 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView9);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spots_custom_listview, arg2,false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
        return row;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        holder.tvTitle.setText(c.getString(5));
        holder.tvt9.setText(c.getString(4));

    }
}
```

Could you help me?

Comment: Post your error logcat

Comment: @PratikButani   No error , I just don't know how to remove a row from database in this listVIew.

Comment: I have answered below, check it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The 3rd parameter from onItemLongClick is the BaseColumns._ID value.

Now, you mention that it returns -1, so, something is wrong with the list or adapter.

Maybe the cursor you are passing to the cursorAdapter does not include the _ID column as part of the projection.

Can you post the code where you create the cursorAdapter?

Comment: thanks for the reply , I attach cursorAdapter class , I'm sure cursor has the _id from database .

Comment: I see no reason to extend cursor adapter here. You should be able to do it fine with the normal cursor adapter, overriding methods and not calling super may give you unexpected results, maybe that is the source of the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
     // First you have to get cursor using position
     Cursor cursor = (Cursor) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);

     //Now you can get id using column name of ROW_ID
     int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("your_row_id_column_name"));

     //Now delete you row
     myDb.deleteRow(id);
}
```

Feel free to ping if any doubt.